# How to convert a list to a dictionary with indexes as values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert the following list:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

To a dictionary like:

```
d = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

I have tried answers from other posts but none is working for me. I have the following code for now:

```
d = {l[i]: i for i in range(len(l))}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: your code works for me.

Comment: 1. Don't use `list` as variable name 2. Use `enumerate` as shown `{j:i for i,j in enumerate(l)}`

Comment: You have a bug in code you haven't shown us. The elements of `list` are probably lists, although you could have made other mistakes, like writing `list: i` instead of `list[i]: i`.

Comment: @user2357112 I edited the post. You are correct that makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Strange that no one noticed what if there are duplicate elements

Comment: For the case where the values repeat, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199627/most-efficient-way-to-reduce-list-to-map) for creating a list of indexes as values

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can get the indices of a list from the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). You just need to reverse the index-value map and use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> {k: v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}
{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}
```

Comment: When using this solution, be aware that duplicates in the original list will result in a single key with the highest value available.

Answer (score 35):

Use built-in functions [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> dict(zip(lst, range(len(lst))))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also take advantage of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
your_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
your_dict = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(your_list)}
```

Comment: why don't you use the item of your for-loop?

Comment: Because you don't have to. I still changed it.

Comment: Just like `list` is reserved, `dict` is too. They're the list and dictionary types, respectively.

Comment: Wow - almost 5 years later and I never realized ha - updated, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Python `dict` constructor has an ability to convert list of `tuple` to `dict`, with key as first element of tuple and value as second element of tuple. To achieve this you can use builtin function  [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which yield `tuple` of `(index, value)`.

However question's requirement is exact opposite i.e. `tuple` should be `(value, index)`. So this requires and additional step to reverse the tuple elements before passing to dict constructor. For this step we can use builtin [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) and apply it to each element of list using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> dict(map(reversed, enumerate(lst)))
>>> {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}
```

Comment: This version seems to take longer than the other solutions provided

Comment: A short solution is nice, but at a cursory glance, it's not clear how `reversed()` is being used.  Because of the extra function calls to `map()` and `reversed()`, it also runs slower than a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

1. If the **elements in target list are unique**, then a dict comprehension should be enough and elegant, just like [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460020/2303761).

   ```py
   >>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
   >>> pos_map = {ele: pos for pos, ele in enumerate(lst)}
   ```
2. But if **there were duplicated elements in target list**, then we could use the handy [`defaultdict` in `collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) module:

   ```py
   >>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B']
   >>> from collections import defaultdict
   >>> pos_map = defaultdict(list)
   >>> for pos, ele in enumerate(lst):
   >>>     pos_map[ele].append(pos)
   >>>
   >>> pos_map
   >>> defaultdict(list, {'A': [0, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 5], 'C': [2]})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the unhashable list into a tuple:

```
dct = {tuple(key): idx for idx, key in enumerate(lst)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I used was:

```
lst = list('ABC')
dict(enumerate(lst))
```

edit: This is the reverse of what the author needed and exactly what I needed

Comment: This will give you {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'} which is different from the wanted result {'A':0, 'B':1, 'C':2}

Comment: Which is also really not necessary. Why have a dict whose keys are sequential integers? It is just a list for all purposes...