# How do I map characters in array in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, one-hot-encoding

I have array

```
a = ['A','A','B']
```

I want to map 'A' to 1 and 'B' to zero. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Convert list to dictionary with indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459969/python-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

```py
[1 if c == 'A' else 0 for c in a]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do data mapping:

```
data = {'A':1, 'B': 0}
print(data['A'])
Out:
1
```