# Python: Convert 2d list to dictionary with indexes as values

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a 2d list with arbitrary strings like this:

```
    lst = [['a', 'xyz' , 'tps'], ['rtr' , 'xyz']]
```

I want to create a dictionary out of this:

```
    {'a': 0, 'xyz': 1, 'tps': 2, 'rtr': 3}
```

How do I do this? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459969/python-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-indexes-as-values) answers for 1D list for non-repeated values, but, I have a 2d list and values can repeat. Is there a generic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use two for-loops:

```
lst = [['a', 'xyz' , 'tps'], ['rtr' , 'xyz']]
d = {}
overall_idx = 0
for sub_lst in lst:
    for word in sub_lst:
        if word not in d:
            d[word] = overall_idx
            # Increment overall_idx below if you want to only increment if word is not previously seen
            # overall_idx += 1
        overall_idx += 1
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 0, 'xyz': 1, 'tps': 2, 'rtr': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert the list of lists to a list using a 'double' list comprehension.

Next, get rid of all the duplicates using a dictionary comprehension, we could use `set` for that but would lose the order.

Finally use another dictionary comprehension to get the desired result.

```py
lst = [['a', 'xyz' , 'tps'], ['rtr' , 'xyz']]

# flatten list of lists to a list
flat_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]

# remove duplicates
ordered_set = {x:0 for x in flat_list}.keys()

# create required output
the_dictionary = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(ordered_set)}

print(the_dictionary)

""" OUTPUT
{'a': 0, 'xyz': 1, 'tps': 2, 'rtr': 3}
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

also, with collections and itertools:

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

lstdict={}
lst = [['a', 'xyz' , 'tps'], ['rtr' , 'xyz']]
lstkeys = list(OrderedDict(zip(itertools.chain(*lst), itertools.repeat(None))))
lstdict = {lstkeys[i]: i for i in range(0, len(lstkeys))}
lstdict
```

output:

```
{'a': 0, 'xyz': 1, 'tps': 2, 'rtr': 3}
```